# Disabling Override in Address Box

Tags: netsuite

I am open to doing this via Forms, Workflows, or Suitescript. None have worked for me so far.

On a transaction, a user can change the bill to or ship to address for a customer. We are having issues due to the users using the Override feature and not the normal "Address Line 1, City, State, Zip" lines. Therefore, we want to disable the override functionality.

I cannot find this on any forms. I have tried workflows - I have disabled it on Before Record Load, Before User Edit, and Before field edit. I could not hide nor disable the Override button in any of these cases. I also tried hiding/disabling the Address free form text box they type in after they hit Override. I did this in all of the above stages as well as After Field Edit for when the Override button is pushed. Lastly, I attempted to just make the address fields mandatory. To do this, I tried setting Address Line 1, City, State, Zip all mandatory and again I tried before record load, before user edit, and before field edit. None actually worked. The workflow in any case would say it fired on Before Record load but when I went to add or edit an address, it still worked.

Part of my confusion comes on what exactly an address is. While the user is doing this on the transaction level (Quote, Sales Order, or Invoice), technically the update stores on the Customer Level. I tried applying the same above workflows on the Customer level with no success.

I am about to try scripting against this, but don't feel very optimistic based on all of the above testing with Workflows.

Has anyone else tried to do any manipulation against the Address on the transaction level? How did you do that? Again, I am open to forms, workflows, or Scripts. If you did it outside of these, please explain.

**EDIT:
I still need help with this. This problem is persisting. Has anyone found a way to disable the "Override" feature on a transaction but still allow the drop down?**

Comment: did you get anywhere ?

Answer (score 0):

Use below as custom code in your address form.

```
/**
*@NApiVersion 2.0
*@NScriptName
*@NScriptType ClientScript
*/
define(['N/currentRecord'],function(currentRecord) {
    function pageInit(context) {
        var field = context.currentRecord.getField({
            fieldId: 'override'
        });
        field.isDisabled = true;
      }

    return {
        pageInit: pageInit
    };
});
```

Comment: I tried adding this to custom code section of custom address entry form, but doesnt seem to do anything, so not sure if i did it right

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work to disable the drop-down select list for the Address on a transaction.  I only tested it on a sales order but the theory should apply to other transactions as well.

```
var DcDisableAddress = {
    beforeLoad : function(type, form) {
        if (type == 'edit') {
            var shipSelect = form.getField('shipaddresslist');
            if (shipSelect) {
                shipSelect.setDisplayType('disabled');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That's not exactly the issue. We want them to be able to select from the drop down. What we don't want is them to be able to use the Override checkbox from the drop down.