# Disabling Override in Address Box and removing the existing overrides in place

Tags: netsuite

[Disabling Override in Address Box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24210767/21315205)

In addition to this link:

Does anyone know how to add an additional code that clears out all the addresses that have "override" selected prior to making "override" no longer accessible?

[Disabling Override in Address Box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24210767/21315205)

Comment: Here, You can add a logic as field changed because it is not possible to remove the list value of standard field. So you can add a logic in fieldChange/validateField  that while a user select override option it should populate any message or replace that value will null.